# Get value of twitter bootstrap radio button group in Meteor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, meteor

I know that the're a lot of topics around this, but unfortunately, I can't find a working solution. So here's my question.

I have a meteor template with following button group in it:

```
<template name="test">
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="search_form">
 <fieldset>
  <div class="form-actions">

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" id="my_radiogroup">
      <button type="radio" class="btn my_button" name="knop" value="1">OR</button>
      <button type="radio" class="btn my_button" name="knop" value="2">AND</button>
    </div>

   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</template>
```

Now I want to get the value of the selected radiobutton (OR or AND). Therefore I tried following solutions, based on what I could find on the web and on Stack:

First solution:

```
Template.test.events({
 'click #my_radiogroup' : function(e,t) {
 var element = t.find('button:radio[name=knop]:checked'); 
 alert($(element).val());
}
});
```

Second solution (based on the active class from twitter bootstrap):

```
Template.test.events({
 'click #my_radiogroup' : function(e,t) {
 var element = t.find("#my_button.active").value;
 alert(element);
}
});
```

I've tried a third solution with this changes in my template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="alignment" value="" />  
<div class="btn-group alignment" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
 <button type="button" class="btn">OR</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn">AND</button>
</div>
```

And with this code in my *.js file:

```
Template.test.events({
 'click #alignment.btn' : function(e,t) {
 var element = val(this.text());
 alert(element);
 return false;
}
});
```

However, none of this solutions works. Who wants how I can get the value of the selected radiobutton?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last example you're trying to target an element with both the id #alignment and the .btn class, which don't exists.

Also I don't know where you get the "t" from, as only an [event map](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) is passed to the [event](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events) (the "e").

This code should work (not tested though).

```
Template.test.events({
  'click .btn' : function(e) {
    var clickedButton = e.currentTarget;
    alert( $(clickedButton).val() );
  }
});
```

Comment: @Kristoffer K : the "t" is the Meteor template instance which is also passed to the event handler.

Comment: @saimeunt : it's not in the documentation? Or do I miss something? Thanks

Comment: The docs: "The handler function receives two arguments: event, an object with information about the event, and template, a template instance for the template where the handler is defined."

Comment: I have a supplement question. What if I want to show the alert that shows which radio button is pressed by pushing another button (not one of the radiobuttons itself)? In that case I can't use e.currentTarget because the currenTarget is not one of the radiobuttons.

Comment: @Quantum just select the radio button which is selected (clicked) using `$('.btn').is(':checked')` for example. You'd probably be better off by using a more specific class than the .btn (which i suspect is from TW bootstrap?), but anyways, something like that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
alert($('.btn-group > .btn.active').attr("value"));
```